# How do you ignore tags with Mustache.java?

Tags: java, mustache, templating

I'm currently trying to set up a site that is rendered on the server side with Mustache.java: https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java

However, for some pages, I need to also render on the client side with Mustache.js. However, Mustache.java processes any tags in the Mustache I want to process only on the client side. How can I make mustache ignore certain tags?

Template:

```
<div>{{process_on_backend}}</div>
<script id="mustache-to-be-rendered-in-browser" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <div>
        {{process_on_frontend}}
    </div>
</script>
```

What I want it to compile to:

```
<div>This should be processed.</div>
<script id="mustache-to-be-rendered-in-browser" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <div>
        {{process_on_frontend}}
    </div>
</script>
```

What it actually compiles to:

```
<div>This should be processed</div>
<script id="mustache-to-be-rendered-in-browser" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <div>
        This should not be processed.
    </div>
</script>
```

I saw in another question that using `{{={{{ }}}=}}` to temporarily change the delimiters might work, but when I tried it, I got a 500 error: `com.github.mustachejava.MustacheException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0` and I'm pretty sure that it isn't supported in mustache.java.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. For some reason using '{' in the new delimiter seems to throw it off. Instead, I used `{{=<% %>=}}` and it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I bet it's trying to match the end of the "change delimiters" tag and getting `{{={{{ }}` then not knowing what to do with it.

Comment: This is definitely what it is doing. Going to open it as an issue.